# Json with parameters in Vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I need to send json data to an API including a QR code and some other values.

this is what i got from them

The needed parameter is:

•   Parameter "data" in JSON:
id -> 100 (fixed, it is the ID needed for our software)
qrcode -> QRcode value

Example: `data={"id":"100","qrcode":"VL11bbdb186a3a6dcfc57a1b07149c9a0e"}`

and this is the code i use

Call:

```
     Dim jsonPost As New JsonPost(postadress)
                Dim dictqr As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                dictqr.Add("id", lastmeas.id)
                dictqr.Add("qrcode", lastmeas.qrcode)
                jsonPost.PostData(dictqr)
```

and this is the definition

```
    Public Class JsonPost

        Private urlToPost As String = ""

        Public Sub New(ByVal urlToPost As String)
            Me.urlToPost = urlToPost
        End Sub

        Public Function PostData(ByVal dictData As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As Boolean
            Dim webClient As New WebClient()
            Dim resByte As Byte()
            Dim resString As String
            Dim reqString() As Byte

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(o, certificate, chain, errors) True
            Try
                webClient.Headers("content-type") = "application/json"
                webClient.Headers("accept") = "*/*"
                reqString = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None))
                resByte = webClient.UploadData(Me.urlToPost, "POST", reqString)
                resString = Encoding.Default.GetString(resByte)
                Form1.respuesta_envio = resString
                webClient.Dispose()
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Form1.respuesta_envio = ex.Message
                CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup(ex.Message, 5, "Data not transfered")
            End Try
            Return False

        End Function

    End Class
```

if i deserialize, i get

```
{"id":"100","qrcode":"example"}
```

but i do not know how to include this data= part

Comment: Are you sure you need `data=`? If you include that, it won't be valid JSON. Check the API provider's documentation. Give us a link to the relevant documentation, if you're unsure, or paste the relevant instructions into your question.

Comment: i only got the API adress, and the data i already included on the first post https://192.168.22.100/fwk/ca/fibertester_start (ignore SSL certificate check)

The needed parameter is:
• Parameter "data" in JSON:
id -> 100 <fixed, it is the ID needed for our software>
qrcode -> <QRcode value>

Example:          data={"id":"100","qrcode":"VL11bbdb186a3a6dcfc57a1b07149c9a0e"}

Comment: `i only got the API adress`...then how do you know what is required to send? Where did you find out, and get told that you need to write `data={...`? P.S. Clearly none of us here can access that URL since it's a local LAN address.

Comment: In the example, i saw what they required, and the posted code properly creates the json. But i do not know how can i pass this "data". According to them, the body in my message is empty (if i deserialize, i get the correct json but without the data=) thats why i think the issue is on the "data=" part

Comment: `According to them`....according to who? `In the example`...what example? Please paste the actual example, with all the required info (e.g. the required content type, any other required headers, any other info). I'll repeat: `data={"id":"100","qrcode":"VL11bbdb186a3a6dcfc57a1b07149c9a0e"}` **is not valid JSON**. If you send that, with a content-type of `application/json`, the server is likely to reject it. Maybe you're supposed to send form-url-encoded data with JSON embedded in it (yuk...but maybe it's an API written by people without a proper understanding of the web?)

Comment: Also, have you tried testing the API in a tool like PostMan where you can create the request manually yourself, and play about with all the headers, data etc until you get a successful response? Also, have you reached out to whoever "them" is and asked for a fuller example, if the information in your question is all that they have told you? It's not sufficient information to be 100% clear what you are supposed to send (in terms of both data and headers).

Comment: The api provider is local italian company. They only info provided the entry point and the example (the one you tell me that is not a valid json). Regarding postman my software is running on a machine that i cant install postman, as it is installed in italy, without internet access (In fact, when i call the API from the software, with the json without the "data=" part, the server answer is 200, but they claim my message was empty...

Comment: `the one you tell me that is not a valid json`...you don't need to take my word for it, just paste it into https://jsonlint.com and you'll see.

Comment: Did the API provider tell you specifically to set `"application/json"` as the content-type or not? I wonder if actually you should set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type. Change that, and also change your code to `reqString = "data=" & Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None))` and see if that works.

Comment: I will try on monday, as i do not have access right now.

Comment: When i tried to put the code on the software, i cant compile. error "& is not defined between string and Byte()

Comment: Ah of course, it should be `Encoding.Default.GetBytes("data=" & JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None))`, I expect.

Comment: Just tested. i got as answer {"result":"ko","error":false,"status":200}. lets see if they got the data or not. this time...

Comment: It worked. Thank you. could you please put it as an Answer, so i can Accept it?

Comment: Done - see below. Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API appears to be asking you to send a JSON string inside a form-url-encoded parameter. That's unpleasant and not a logical way to design an API, but if that's what they require then that's what you'll have to do.

Therefore you need to:

- remove the Content-Type header telling the server to expect a JSON body in the request. What you'll actually be sending is form-url-encoded data where the one parameter happens to contain JSON within its value. i.e. remove this line:

```
webClient.Headers("content-type") = "application/json"
```

- prepend the `data=` bit to the JSON string generated by the SerializeObject function:

```
reqString = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("data=" & JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None))
```